# help embedding some html in a webpage

Tags: html, css

I don't know much css or html, so I have a question about taking html that looks like this:
[html code paste](http://codepad.org/JDNQpwKg) and putting into another page.

The problem is when I just copy and paste this into a webpage is completely messes up the background (turns it black) and overwrites other settings. How can I take that exported html and css so that I can paste the code I exported from emacs into a webpage and not kill other settings?
Ideally it would appear just as it currently looks but in a little box inside the rest of the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [IFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: any way to do that without the scroll bars?

Comment: yes you can set the height and width of your iFrame as attributes on the tag

Comment: add this to the stylesheet section html { overflow: hidden }

Comment: @durilai That's a horrible idea unless you want to end up hiding content from users.

Comment: @DN, it gets rid of scroll bars doesn't it? Never said anything about not hiding content.

Comment: @durilai Right, it's just that the consequence is big. A consequence is part of a solution, and has to be taken into account.

Comment: I'd like the iframe to not have scroll bars, and take up as much space as needed to display the content. I don't want to set the width/height in pixels since different browsers can display that fonts in different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the desired HTML/CSS/etc in another file. Call this `file2.html`
2. In your main file, use an [`OBJECT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html) element to embed this document.

   ```
   <object data="file2.html" type="text/html">
       <a href="file2.html">View file2</a>
   </object>
   ```

This will create a "box" with your file inside. You can style the `OBJECT` element in any way you wish. Removing scrollbars, adjusting the width, etc.
If a browser does not support the `OBJECT` element, then they will see the link directly to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also paste the code someplace like http://gist.github.com/ or http://pastie.org/ where they also give you some code to embed the code snippet in your site/weblog/etc.

You can see an example of the embedded code (for gist.github.com) here: http://github.com/blog/605-new-languages-highlighted